# Postman Error: 403

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I am trying to send REST calls with Postman. I am using the collection from here:

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/postman

I am trying to retrieve the discovery document and got the error below:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am fairly certain that the end points and client credentials are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the profile for the app credentials I was using did not have permission to access that endpoint. Rookie Error :(